# Check for duplicate files using MediaStore Api

Tags: android, mediastore

I have an app that downloads files in `byte[]` form. The file can be an image, doc or a pdf. However, when I am using `MediaStore` api to save the file into my android device, if the file already exists before (i.e. already downloaded), then it appends a (1) to the end of the file and saves it. Is there anyway to check for the duplicate so that I can prevent it from saving the file?

My code below:

```
    OutputStream outputStream;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();


        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Downloads.DISPLAY_NAME, "SampleFile" + fileNumber + "." + extension);
        Log.d("debugsave" ,"display name : " + contentValues.get(MediaStore.Downloads.DISPLAY_NAME).toString());
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Downloads.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpg");
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Downloads.RELATIVE_PATH, JOBSEEKER_DIR + "/JobId_" + jobId);
        Log.d("debugsave" ,"relative path: " + contentValues.get(MediaStore.Downloads.RELATIVE_PATH).toString());

        Uri uri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);

        Log.d("debugsave" ,"after insert : " + contentValues.get(MediaStore.Downloads.DISPLAY_NAME).toString());

        Log.d("debugsave", "uri " + uri.toString());
        outputStream = resolver.openOutputStream(uri);
        Log.d("debugsave" ,"after resolver : " + resolver.getType(uri));

    } else {
        String imageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(JOBSEEKER_DIR).toString();
        File image = new File(imageDir, "SampleFile" + fileNumber + "." + extension);

        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(image);
    }

    if (isImage) {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);
    } else {
        outputStream.write(data);
    }

    outputStream.close();
```

I tried debugging some values from content values, but I cannot seem to get where the file name is changing and the (1) is being appended.

Comment: Yes. Before downloading you can query the media store for an existing DISPLAY_NAME and RELATIVE_PATH for the specific collection. If you get a cursor an an uri you can then decide to download again (overwrite) using that uri or to not do that.

Comment: I understand the logic, but I am not at all familiar with the implementation of querying the media store. Can you please refer me a code snippet or some kind of reference?

Comment: Have a look at stackoverflow pages tagged `mediastore` for examples.

Comment: `Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);` It is not a good idea to use an intermediate bitmap (didnt i tell yo that before?). You can write that array directly to the outputstream. Now you are changing file sizes. Compare original and new one to see. If you dont use a bitmap you can download and store any file. Not only png and jpg.

Comment: I see, I didnt know that you do not need a intermediate bitmap for image files. I will update my code accordingly